# Can't get generated content to push footer down

Tags: theming, nodes

I have been hitting my CSS head against the wall for hours now.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but I sure would appreciate some insight.

I've got a view that is populated by a content type that has an image and text.  I've tried at least three sticky footer approaches and none worked.

We took bartik and modified the CSS as we've moved forward.  I don't know if there's some css remnant of bartik wreaking havoc or my own CSS ineptitude.  But we need to get it fixed and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Scott.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, never modify a core theme. Sub-theme. :) Second, the problem is that you are specifying "position:absolute" on some of your blocks which causes the CSS box-model to ignore any content inside the wrapper divs. When you write absolute, you are telling the browser: I know exactly where my content will be and so therefore you should ignore any flowing you want to do.

Try moving away from using position:absolute to position elements and instead use floats which will push the content region height and, in turn, your footer.

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: I didn't modify a main theme.  Took bartik as a starting point and themed in sites/all/themes.

Comment: Excellent! Then you're already on your way to greatness, my friend. (It was damn late when I was posting)

Comment: No worries.  It was late when I posted the Q as well.  Your post got me rethinking how I was setting things up, so thanks!

Comment: Would like to know the solution when you find it...